# Account getAccountRecordTypeId

Tags: java

I want to ask my Salesforce for Account ID, based on Account Name.The problem is what am I going to put into the "where" part of my query?

**My interface:**

```
Account getAccountRecordTypeId(String recordName) throws ConnectionException;
```

**My Query:**

```
@Override
public Account getAccountRecordTypeId(String recordName) throws ConnectionException {
    // @formatter:off
    String sql =
            "select "
                    + " RecordTypeId "
                    + " from Account "
                    + " where ????? = '" + recordName + "' ";

    // @formatter:on
    return getSingleResultOrNull(query(sql, Account.class));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the query

```
Select Id from Account where Name = 'recordName'
```

But please note

- RecordTypeId is different from Record Id (Id).
- You will get multiple records matching the name (if there are multiple accounts with the same name)
- You have to handle the result of the query for 1 or more records and also consider when there's no matching data
- SOQL is not SQL so you should understand how you refer the objects & fields and the relationship queries (joins) between related objects